# Regex & Phone Numbers

Tags: c#, regex, phone-number

So I have been working on creating a regex to validate phone numbers in the following format XXX-XXX-XXXX which has been working pretty well so far, but now I'm trying to figure out how to remove the ability to enter specific numbers like "123-456-7890".

My current regex is

```
(^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$)
```

I've been looking into it for a few days, but I can't seem to figure out what to add to my current expression in order to get "any number with formats XXX-XXX-XXXX BUT NOT 123-456-7890"

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you so much

Comment: A tricky one, Regex are usually done to match things, not to not match them. I wonder if isn't easier doing it in regular c# coding `if (myString != "123-435-7890" && Regex.Match(myString, "^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$"))`

Answer (score 3):

If negative look-ahead is supported in whatever version you're running, this should work:

```
(^(?!123-456-7890)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$)
```

It's the same expression you used, just with a negative look-ahead added in the beginning.
`(?!123-456-7890)` checks if the character sequence ahead doesn't match the pattern '123-456-7890'.
Only if this condition is met, the rest of the pattern will be considered.

The same can be done by checking *after* matching the pattern using the look-behind expression `(?<!123-456-7890)`

```
(^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}(?<!123-456-7890)$)
```

in case that's faster or more practical for you.

https://regex101.com/r/GOyOgf/1

Answer (score 2):

I would break them into 2 regexes for simplicity and you can use an alternation for the not matches, like this:

```
        var regexToMatch = new Regex("(^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$)");
        var regexToNotMatch = new Regex("(123-456-7890)|(098-765-4321)");
        
        var testString = "123-456-7890";
        
        if(regexToMatch.IsMatch(testString) && !regexToNotMatch.IsMatch(testString))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Valid!");    
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not Valid!");
        }
```

And here's a working fiddle of it.